# Well i am facing a 'attribute error: test' while trying to run wolfram alpha in python

Tags: python

When i am executing it the following is showing up
File "C:\users\vasu\anaconda3_\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha__init__.py", line 86, in **getattr**
val = self[name] if name in self else self[attr_name]

KeyError: '@test'

During handling of above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback(most recent call last);
File "C:\Users\VASU\anaconda3_\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha__init__.py", line 88, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError(name)

AttributeError: test

Below is the code I used

```
import wolframalpha
question = input('Question: ')
app_id = ‘Your app_id’
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id) 
res = client.query(question) 
answer = next(res.results).text 
print(answer)
```

I hope You can help me out in this

Comment: Why did you expect that the attribute `test` exists?

Comment: Sorry for that its not test, its text.

Comment: If it is indeed text then please edit your question. Furthermore, probably you we're trying to call the text attribute on your RES, not on your next. You should probably check if the query came back with a valid result in the first place. Encapsulate this in a try-except clause and use a debugger to figure out what the answer and client variables contain.